# WebStorm inspector throws warning when setting initial React state with ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webstorm, babeljs

I've been working on a React web app and have recently upgraded from WebStorm 10 to 2016.1. I've been pleased with the new version so far, save for a couple of inspector quirks that I'd rather not have present if I can help it, one of which I have not been able to find a fix for.

I'm using ES6 classes for the the declaration of all of my React components and in every instance where I am setting a state, WebStorm is throwing an unresolved variable warning on the `.state` method.

Code snippet in question:

```
import React from "react";
import autobind from 'autobind-decorator';

@autobind
class List extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      name: "List",
      items: {},
      history: {},
      suggestions: [],
      highlightIndex: 0,
      suggestionsHover: false,
      autoDelete: true,
      delta: 0,
      mouse: 0,
      isPressed: false,
      lastPressed: 0,
      order: []
    }
  }
```

The warning:

```
Unresolved variable state
```

It should be noted that this warning did not appear for me in WebStorm 10 and that the warning carries over to other instances of setting state (ie `.setState`). It should also be noted that I am using babelify to transpile my code down to ES5 as well as autobind-decorator as shown.

Any help or insight would be appreciated. Thanks and let me know if I need to provide any other information.

Comment: Sounds somewhat similar -- have a look at last comments -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206559169-WebStorm-2016-1-seems-to-have-lost-React-recognition

Answer (score 12):

Try setting up code assistance with a TypeScript definition file. I do not mean transition your code to TypeScript. Check out this blog post from JetBrains about the subject:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/10/working-with-reactjs-in-webstorm-coding-assistance/

Basically, go into WebStorm's preferences. Down in: `Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries` click the `Download` button. Search for `React` (and whatever else is in that list that could help), then click `Download & Install`. This should help remove some of those ugly warnings.

Now, if only WebStorm would be able to apply PropTypes to the `props` object, we'd be able to get those "unresolved variable/functions/method" warnings to go away.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! It was very useful to use the TypeScript definitions even in ES6 environment. I managed to get rid of my `import {Component} from 'react'` warnings.

Comment: This is fantastic – it got rid of my "Unresolved function or method setState()" and related issues.

Comment: your answer is great!

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue.

The bug has been fixed in version 2016.2 (see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20884).

As soon as this update lands, `this.state`, `this.props` and other currently unresolved variables will be resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add props into your constructor

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
```